# Write detected errors within a batch script to a file?

Tags: batch-file

I am executing a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) which uses the `javac` command and compiles a `.java` file. I want to save the output of this command to a text file ... but the problem is, if errors are detected, the output file is blank.

```
@echo we have started compiling program
javac programs\abc.java > output_abc.txt && type output_abc.txt
PAUSE
EXIT
```

In case an error occurs then that error should also be written into the file.

Comment: `javac programs\abc.java > output_abc.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Correct !!!! Thanks

Comment: [you probably want to use](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) `&` instead of `&&`

Comment: Try this: `javac programs\abc.java > output_abc.txt 2> error_abc.txt && type output_abc.txt || type error_abc.txt`